# JavaScript pop box won't work properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with this script. When I press 'yes' it deletes the user which is fine. My problem is that it still deletes the user when I click cancel. Any ideas?

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Are You Want To Delete This User ?") == true) {
        x = "delete.php";
    } else {
        x = "memberlist.php";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}    
</script>
```

Comment: You might need to show a little more code since all this does is make a box (`#demo`) contain the string "delete.php" or "memberlist.php".  Based on what you have here, it looks ok.  Also `== true` is redundant in a conditional.

Comment: This part of JavaScript code is working properly.

Comment: @arcyqwerty probably not relevant here but `== true` might be a code style requirement. It would have to be `=== true` though.

Comment: sorry cant understand . can you correct this ?

Comment: Seems to work just as expected when the function is called

Comment: Are you maybe trying to change a form's submission url or something?

Comment: no i want to delete users from data table. i used it to reduce errors. but i dont know y its still  delete when i press cancel

Comment: what element is #demo ?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned JavaScript works fine. It may be that there is some issue in your delete.php or memberlist.php code. For a solution as per your expectations, please provide the code for delete.php and memberlist.php.

Answer (score 0):

you can add confirm in your url

Edit : sory about spelling mistake i just want to show an alternative way i am texting on phone

```
<a onclick="return confirm('you are going to delet it are you sure bobo ?')" href="#your delet url">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume your element is a link with "delete.php" as href - that is a VERY bad idea unless you want google spider to delete your database
2. You need to return false on a link's click event if you do not want it to execute - but see 1

I suggest

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("deleteLink").onclick=function() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete?") {
      location="delete.php?user="+this.getAttribute("data-user");
    }
  }
  return false // cancel link
}
```

using

```
<a href="#" id="deleteLink" data-user="Frank">Delete</a>
```

Generic for more than one user:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteLink");
  for (var i=0;i<deleteLinks.length;i++) {
    deleteLinks[i].onclick=function() {
      var user = this.getAttribute("data-user");
      if (confirm("Do you really want to delete "+user+"?") {
        location="delete.php?user="+user;
      }
    }
  }
  return false // cancel link
}
```

using

```
<a href="#" class="deleteLink" data-user="Frank">Delete Frank</a>
<a href="#" class="deleteLink" data-user="Bob">Delete Bob</a>
```